# ChromeOS linux show in folder

Tags: linux, chromebook, google-chrome-os, xdg

When I click 'show in folder' in a Linux app running on Chrome OS, Visual Studio Code will be launched. I would much prefer the Chrome OS built in file manager to display the folder.

I have found the xdg default is set incorrectly, as expected:

```bsh
tomux@penguin:~$ xdg-mime query default inode/directory
code.desktop
```

What can I change this to so that it instead launches the Chrome OS file manager?